# Texture looks fine in Rendered 3D View, but gets "Striped" when I try to bake it

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I'm pretty new in Blender. Created simple model, unwrapped it, then found some free textures in the Internet, and applied them to my object, mostly using either Object or UV coordinates for this. After that object looks fine in 3D Rendered view, but when I try to bake it to get single Texture file to be able to export model to game later - somewhy some of textures got "striped", looking like having odd scale or projection.

This happens not every time I try to bake it - it baked fine once, but then I've changed UV Map a bit and tried again - it looks goofed up again. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Rendered view, baked img view and bake settings screenshot]

[image]